# Spark to HCatalog without Spark SQL

Tags: java, apache-spark, cloudera, hcatalog

How to connect to HCatalog from a Spark Job without using Spark SQL.

WE are using Cloudera distribution of Spark, in that currently they don't have support for Spark SQL.

Is there any other way we can connect o HCatalog from a Spark Job?

Answer (score 1):

Why not connect to the HCatalog REST server via WebHCat?  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/WebHCat

That can be done without relying upon the Cloudera spark / SparkSQL integration.